Почему userId в metadata не добавляется?
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { SubscriptionDto } from './dto/subscription.dto';

@Injectable()
export class StripeService {
  private stripe: Stripe;

  constructor() {
    this.stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
      apiVersion: '2024-10-28.acacia',
    })
  }

  subscription(dto: SubscriptionDto) {
    const totalPrice = dto.amount
    const redirectUrl = dto.redirectUrl
    const userId = dto.userId

    return this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: 'subscription',
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            unit_amount: Math.round(totalPrice * 100), // cents 
            product_data: {
              name: 'Cart Payment',
              metadata: { // userId
                userId,
              },
            },
            recurring: {
              interval: 'month',
              interval_count: 1
            }
          },
          quantity: 1,
          
        },
      ],
      metadata: {
        userId,
      },
      success_url: redirectUrl,
      cancel_url: redirectUrl,
      client_reference_id: userId,
    });  
  }

  constructEvent(payload: any, signature: any) {
    return this.stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, signature, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
  }
}


import { Controller, Post, Headers, HttpCode, HttpStatus, RawBody, Body, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StripeService } from 'src/stripe/stripe.service';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';

@Controller('webhook')
export class WebhookController implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    private stripeService: StripeService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => any) {
    bodyParser.raw({type: '*/*'})(req, res, next);
  }

  @Post()
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async handleWebhook(@RawBody() payload: Buffer, @Headers('stripe-signature') signature: string) {
    const event = this.stripeService.constructEvent(payload, signature);

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'customer.subscription.created':
        // Обработка успешной сессии оплаты
        console.log('YES   customer.subscription.created  ', event.data.object.metadata?.userId); // undefined
        break;
      case 'customer.subscription.deleted':
        // Обработка отмененной подписки
        console.log('YES   customer.subscription.deleted  ', event.data.object.metadata?.userId);
        break;
      default: 
        // console.warn(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        break;
    }
  }}


'use client';

import { axiosWithAuth } from '@/api/interceptors';
import { absoluteUrl } from '@/lib/absolute-url';
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/use-user-store';

const Payment = () => {
    const { user } = useUserStore();

    const handleClick = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await axiosWithAuth.post(`/stripe/subscription`, {
            userId: user?.id,
            amount: 1, // dollars
            redirectUrl: absoluteUrl('/test'),
        });
        console.log('res  ', res.data?.url);

        window.location.href = res.data?.url;
    };
    return (
        <form onClick={handleClick}>
            <h1>dddddddd</h1>

            <button type='submit'>PAY</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Payment;

